# Conversion between decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: c++, hex

```
unsigned int hex_vale, some_decimal_constant, some_other_decimal_constant;

for(10,000 times){
if(hex_value == some_decimal_constant){
        call_some_function();
    }
else if(hex_value == some_other_decimal_constant){
        call_some_other_function();     
    }
}
```

In the above function to execute if loop I have to convert either hex into decimal or vice versa. I dont want to convert hex to decimal for 10000 times. Can you please help me with conversion of decimal to hex and the hex number should be stored in unsigned integer.

Comment: I think if you cannot write "for 10000 times" in real C++, you may have to start a bit lower.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you put a value in the variable `hex_value` that makes you think you need to do some conversion?

Comment: Ajay Bidari, your question would be more clear to us if we could see more code. Would you please create a complete program that does approximately what you want? Then we would better understand what your missing. http://SSCCE.ORG

Comment: A function writes some addresses into an array without prefixing them with "0x". I have to search for a particular address and call some functions. Thats why I have two if conditions in the above code. I am not able to put in code snippet to be able to post it here. Its fairly big code.

Comment: how does the function write the addresses? As strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to perform any conversions. The numbers are stored in binary. In this context, hex and decimal are just different literal or character representations of these binary numbers.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  const int a = 32;
  const int b = 0x20;
  std::cout << (a==b) << "\n"; // prints "true"

}
```

Comment: That true only if the hexadecimal numbers begin with 0x. Lets suppose hex_value does not begin with 0x but its a hexadecimal number..

Comment: @ajaybidari if it does not start with `0x`, it is not a hexadecimal number in C++.